# NaN in custom sparse softmax for pointing networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, softmax

I am trying to implement some sort of [pointing network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03134). Since the output of the pointing layer has no fixed dimension, I had to implement some sort of masking of the output, and I came out with this:

```
class Attention(object):
    """Attention mechanism implementation."""

    def __init__(self, attention_states, attention_size, mask=None):
        """Initializes a new instance of the Attention class."""
        self._states = attention_states
        self._attention_size = attention_size
        self._batch = tf.shape(self._states)[0]
        self._length = tf.shape(self._states)[1]
        self._size = self._states.get_shape()[2].value  # statically defined
        self._mask = mask
        self._features = None

    def _init_features(self):
        states = tf.reshape(
            self._states, [self._batch, self._length, 1, self._size])
        weights = tf.get_variable(
            "kernel", [1, 1, self._size, self._attention_size])
        self._features = tf.nn.conv2d(states, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")

    def get_weights(self, query, scope=None):
        """Reurns the attention weights for the given query."""
        with tf.variable_scope(scope or "Attention"):
            if self._features is None:
                self._init_features()
            else:
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            vect = tf.get_variable("Vector", [self._attention_size])
            with tf.variable_scope("Query"):
                query_features = linear(query, self._attention_size, False)
                query_features = tf.reshape(
                    query_features, [-1, 1, 1, self._attention_size])

        activations = vect * tf.tanh(self._features + query_features)
        activations = tf.reduce_sum(activations, [2, 3])
        exp_acts = tf.exp(activations)

        # NOTE: what follows is a custom implementation of
        # something equivalent to a sparse softmax.
        if self._mask is not None:
            exp_acts = exp_acts * self._mask
        sum_exp_acts = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(exp_acts, axis=-1), 1)
        weights = tf.div(exp_acts, sum_exp_acts)
        return weights
```

After some training steps, I have some `NaN` occurring the `weights` tensor. I couldn't figure out *why* this happens, but googling around, I came up to [this discussion about something similar](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3162) that might happen in `theano`. Could it be caused by some saturation in the softmax implementation I had to mimic in order not to keep in account the zeroes?

Thanks in advance,
Giulio

Comment: You should probably use the numeric check [ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/check_ops/) and trace up from where it is. You'll typically want to clip the gradient.

Comment: Well, actually it looks that the NaN is not in the gradient but in the softmax, so *before* the gradients. I changed the piece of code from the `exp_acts` definition and below the `#NOTE...` comment block in this way:
1. activations = softplus of  activations (so that everything is > 0)
2. activations = activations * masks (so that useless items are at 0, which is the lowest value)
3. weights = softmax of activations

In this way, the ranking among the values is preserved and everything is stable -- but the gradient is not exactly the same of a sparse softmax, which I am still aiming.